# Can't connect to VM running Django

Tags: django, http, virtual-machine, virtualbox, portforwarding

Using VirtualBox, I have a NAT enabled VM running Centos 7. The host OS is Windows 7. I can't seem to access the Django web server running inside the VM. What am I missing?

I have two port forwarding rules set for the Virtual Machine:

[image: Port Forwarding Rules]

I start the Django web server on the guest OS with:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And I try to visit the webpage on the host OS at:

```
http://localhost:8000
```

Google Chrome gives me the error code `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

The result of `curl` on the host OS:

```
[user@win7 ~ ]$ curl http://localhost:8000
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Here is the result of a `netstat` performed on the guest OS:

```
[user@vm ~ ]$ netstat -na | grep 8000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Here is the result of a `netstat` performed on the host OS (with Cygwin):

```
[user@win7 ~ ]$ netstat -na | grep 8000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

It is also worth mentioning that the SSH rule works. I can SSH into the machine with no problems.

Comment: You forgot to mention what happens when you reach `http://localhost:8000`. Is there a timeout?

Comment: @Zopieux The results are now in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a solution, but a work-around for my problem.** Maybe this will help anyone encountering a problem similar to mine, and just wants to be able to connect to their VM's webserver.

Since SSH was working, I figured I could access the webpage via a SSH Tunnel. The syntax for doing so via command line is:

```
ssh -L <local-port>:<remote-host>:<remote-port>
```

So in my situation, if I wanted to open a tunnel via command line I would do:

```
ssh -L 8000:127.0.0.1:8000
```

This would allow me to browse to `http://localhost:8000` and access the website.

You can also do this via PuTTY, but I won't explain that here, so just Google for a guide.

Answer (score 0):

The ssh tunnel is an OK work around, but the problem is almost certainly CentOS 7 which now uses firewalld rather than iptables to manager access.  And, unlike iptables the default configuration is quite restrictive.

if

> ps -ae | grep firewall

returns something like

> 602 ?            00:00:00 firewalld

your system is running firewalld, not iptables.  They do not run together.

To correct your VM so you can access your django site from the host use the commands:

> firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8000/tcp --permanent
>
> firewall-cmd --reload

Many thanks to pablo v in the post "Access django server on virtual Machine" for pointing this out.